# I'm trying to setup Trent's datetimepicker and timepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker, datetimepicker, timepicker

I'm trying to setup Trent's datetimepicker and timepicker. I have jQuery Datepicker setup and working. I added everything the docs said to include but just can't get it to work.
Here is a link to my test page where the datepicker is working but datetimepicker is not.
http://testsite.shadownetwest.com/datepicker4/index2.html

Can anyone could tell me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Hiya **Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/HaxfY/1/show/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/HaxfY/1/

you were missing these 2 src and If I may suggest mention `type` of the input as well as end it using `/` :)

Hope this helps: (please feel free to add your default function in jquery code)

Donot forget to accept the answer. :P

**code**

```
  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

**And**

```
$(function(){

    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        onSelect: function(){
            if ($('input[name="endDate"]').val() == '') {
              var edate = $('input[name="begDate"]').val();
              $('input[name="endDate"]').val(edate);
            }
        }
    });
     $('#timepicker').timepicker({});
     $("#datetimepicker").datetimepicker();

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I took your demo and stripped out all on needed code got just the code I needed. Here is a link to my new code, http://testsite.shadownetwest.com/datepicker4/index4.html

Comment: @user1454812 NO worries Glad I can help :) Hey dont forget to accept the answer, its a "tick" which you need to select <on the left hand side of my post> coz your accpet rate will get affected, and for that sake always accept the answers if you get one in stackoverflow. <mentioning since you are new> B-) , cheers

Comment: @Tats_innit, i am not able to show the icon besides the date input field using the following code:`$(“#from-datetime”).datetimepicker({
showOn:’both’,
buttonImage:’res/images/calendar.gif’,
buttonImageOnly:true,
changeMonth:true,
changeYear:true
});`